# Why aren't my simple HTML/CSS Media Queries AND child box locations working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, multiple-columns

Okay, so I'm very new to learning cs languages and I know that there must be a simple solution to my errors but I've been at it for over 24 hours now so I think it's time to ask for help! Neither of the following two goals are working with the code I've written:

Goal #1: Have 3 Parent boxes that contain some text AND a child box that will act as a title for the section. The child box should sit FLUSH in the top right-hand corner of the parent box. (All three child boxes are floating in the center on the right. I have fumbled with margins and cannot get them at the top of their parents!)

Goal #2: Set media queries so that desktop view (lg) = min width of 992px AND tablet view (md) = max width of 991px and min width of 768px AND mobile view (sm) = max width of 767px.

Goal #3: Set column layout to show 3 columns on desktop view, 2 columns on tablet view, and 1 column on mobile view. I can only seem to enable 1 column to show up no matter what the screen size is.

**You should know - I am not permitted to use bootstrap or any other framework.

**You should know - I have only tried viewing different screen sizes by manually expanding/shrinking my 13" laptop screen AND by viewing various sizing through the Chrome Developer Tools.

**You should know - The code for the bigger, Parent boxes is styled in: p AND the code for the smaller, title boxes is styled in: .child-one, .child-two, and .child-three (because I needed them to be three different background colors and I'm not permitted to add any styling to my HTML doc).

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide and don't hesitate to let me know if you need more information!

Tried:styles.css (see below) and simple html (at bottom).
Using: Sublime Text (browser-sync working fine)
Expected: 3 parent boxes (each containing a child (title) box to sit flush in top-right corner), responsive design based on media queries, and lg devices to show 3 columns per row, md devices to show 2 columns per row, and sm devices to show 1 column per row.

```css
style code : styles.css
/* solution styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Rockwell", fantasy;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #D9E4FF;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.child-one {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #8BABF1;
  position: top-right;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size-adjust: relative;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.child-two {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #8B95F6;
  position: top-right;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size-adjust: relative;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.child-three {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #9B8BF4;
  position: top-right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Rockwell";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size-adjust: relative;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Simple Responsive Framework. */

.row {
  width: 100%;
}


/********** Desktop View **********/

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    border: 1px black;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/********** Tablet View **********/

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12,
  {
    border: 1px black;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/********** Mobile View **********/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    border: 1px black;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Module 2 Solution</h1>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <p>Instead of eating chicken, consider eating unsalted nuts and seeds in order to take in low-fat protein.
      <div class="child-one"><span>Not Chicken.</span></div>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <p>Instead of eating beef, consider eating mushrooms, which are low in calories yet rich in fiber and protein.
      <div class="child-two"><span>Never Beef!</span></div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <p>Sushi doesn't have to contain fish! Did you know that tuna (bluefin) is listed as "endangered" by the Center for Biological Diversity? Please stop eating them!
      <div class="child-three">.
        <span>Modified Sushi?</span></div>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: *None of the following THREE goals are working! oop :]

Comment: .col-md-1,
            .col-md-2,
            .col-md-3,
            .col-md-4,
            .col-md-5,
            .col-md-6,
            .col-md-7,
            .col-md-8,
            .col-md-9,
            .col-md-10,
            .col-md-11,
            .col-md-12, remove comma after 12 and then check

Comment: good find but sadly it resulted in no change. thanks for trying, Nisha!

Comment: the issue is  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> all the elements are inside it you don't have other columns so how col will work

Comment: .row {
            width: 100%;  
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        } add this in row and  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> you are adding all data inside just this instead of this you need to create 3 columns not all data in 1 column

Comment: I change below script. can you check it

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: "Rockwell", fantasy;
            font-size: 150%;
            margin: 30px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        p {
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: #D9E4FF;
            position: relative;
            /* margin: 8px; */
            padding: 5px;
            overflow-wrap: anywhere;
            font-family: "Rockwell";
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 100%;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .child-one {
            border: 3px solid black;
            background-color: #8BABF1;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family: "Rockwell";
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size-adjust: relative;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .child-two {
            border: 3px solid black;
            background-color: #8B95F6;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family: "Rockwell";
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size-adjust: relative;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .child-three {
            border: 3px solid black;
            background-color: #9B8BF4;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family: "Rockwell";
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size-adjust: relative;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* Simple Responsive Framework. */

        .row {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }


        /********** Desktop View **********/

        @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

            .col-lg-1,
            .col-lg-2,
            .col-lg-3,
            .col-lg-4,
            .col-lg-5,
            .col-lg-6,
            .col-lg-7,
            .col-lg-8,
            .col-lg-9,
            .col-lg-10,
            .col-lg-11,
            .col-lg-12 {
                border: 1px black;
            }

            .col-lg-1 {
                width: 8.33%;
            }

            .col-lg-2 {
                width: 16.66%;
            }

            .col-lg-3 {
                width: 25%;
            }

            .col-lg-4 {
                width: 33.33%;
            }

            .col-lg-5 {
                width: 41.66%;
            }

            .col-lg-6 {
                width: 50%;
            }

            .col-lg-7 {
                width: 58.33%;
            }

            .col-lg-8 {
                width: 66.66%;
            }

            .col-lg-9 {
                width: 74.99%;
            }

            .col-lg-10 {
                width: 83.33%;
            }

            .col-lg-11 {
                width: 91.66%;
            }

            .col-lg-12 {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .row {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
        }


        /********** Tablet View **********/

        @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {

            .col-md-1,
            .col-md-2,
            .col-md-3,
            .col-md-4,
            .col-md-5,
            .col-md-6,
            .col-md-7,
            .col-md-8,
            .col-md-9,
            .col-md-10,
            .col-md-11,
            .col-md-12 {
                border: 1px black;
            }

            .col-md-1 {
                width: 8.33%;
            }

            .col-md-2 {
                width: 16.66%;
            }

            .col-md-3 {
                width: 25%;
            }

            .col-md-4 {
                width: 33.33%;
            }

            .col-md-5 {
                width: 41.66%;
            }

            .col-md-6 {
                width: 50%;
            }

            .col-md-7 {
                width: 58.33%;
            }

            .col-md-8 {
                width: 66.66%;
            }

            .col-md-9 {
                width: 74.99%;
            }

            .col-md-10 {
                width: 83.33%;
            }

            .col-md-11 {
                width: 91.66%;
            }

            .col-md-12 {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }


        /********** Mobile View **********/

        @media (max-width: 767px) {

            .col-sm-1,
            .col-sm-2,
            .col-sm-3,
            .col-sm-4,
            .col-sm-5,
            .col-sm-6,
            .col-sm-7,
            .col-sm-8,
            .col-sm-9,
            .col-sm-10,
            .col-sm-11,
            .col-sm-12 {
                border: 1px black;
            }

            .col-sm-1 {
                width: 8.33%;
            }

            .col-sm-2 {
                width: 16.66%;
            }

            .col-sm-3 {
                width: 25%;
            }

            .col-sm-4 {
                width: 33.33%;
            }

            .col-sm-5 {
                width: 41.66%;
            }

            .col-sm-6 {
                width: 50%;
            }

            .col-sm-7 {
                width: 58.33%;
            }

            .col-sm-8 {
                width: 66.66%;
            }

            .col-sm-9 {
                width: 74.99%;
            }

            .col-sm-10 {
                width: 83.33%;
            }

            .col-sm-11 {
                width: 91.66%;
            }

            .col-sm-12 {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Module 2 Solution</h1>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="child-one col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">first </div>
        <p class="child-two col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Instead of eating chicken, consider eating unsalted nuts and
            seeds in
            order to tak in low-fat protein.</p>
        <div class="child-three col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><span>Not Chicken.</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="child-one col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">second</div>
        <p class="child-two col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Instead of eating beef, consider eating mushrooms, which are
            low in
            calories yet rich in fiber and
            protein. </p>
        <div class="child-three col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><span>Never Beef!</span></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="child-one col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> third</div>
        <p class="child-two col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">Sushi doesn't have to contain fish! Did you know that tuna
            (bluefin) is listed as
            "endangered" by the
            Center for Biological Diversity? Please stop eating them! </p>
        <div class="child-three col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">.
            <span>Modified Sushi?</span>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried to use that code but all it did was remove my box borders and add the "first" outside of the first box!

Comment: adding the "flex" and "wrap" did not change anything. i must be misunderstanding you :/

Comment: can you tell me it's 3 column what data will come inside. Do you have a pic or something what you want

Comment: i put the description of what i'm trying to code for in my original question (Goal #1, 2, & 3.) sorry if they're not clear!

Comment: i solved my first problem so now i have a box floating in the top right corner of its parent box! (thanks @ João Pimentel Ferreira )

unfortunately, there is still a bug in my row / column code & media queries...

Comment: Please provide details in your answer, not only code.